# Xcode doesn't build for iPhone simulator

Tags: xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator, xcode4.5

I'm working on a iOS project in Xcode 4.5 and I have a workspace with some old libraries that I needed to link as dependancies to my project. I had to go through quite some difficulties before getting it to build and now it finally builds for my device, but not for the simulator. The problem is, I get a bunch of errors like the following (all related to UIKit framework):

```
- error: 'UIResponder' is unavailable: not available on Mac OS X
```

and then it just says `too many errors emitted, stopping now`.
It looks like it's trying to build the project for Mac OS X rather than for iOS, and I have no idea why.

I'm quite new to Xcode 4.5 development and it might just be that I missed something really easy, but I can't seem to find the solution anywhere!
How can I convince Xcode that the iPhone simulator is not Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the deployment target is the latest (6.1), the base SDK is iOS 6.1 and targeted device family is iPhone. All these options can be found under the build settings tab for the PROJECT. [image]